# Validation Check for dynamic textbox with individual submit button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, simple-form

I am trying to create something like the image below.
[Each section is dynamically generated using simple-form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK9X0.png)

Every time the button save is click, it would need to validate the text field (check if it is an integer), send an ajax to the controller and not redirect to any page. 
The code I wrote only managed to check the first field but not able to check the rest. How do I make it so each button only checks / submit ajax of the corresponding textbox?
Here is my code

```
- @students.each do |student|
  .same-category
    .collapsible-container
      .collapsible-head
        .wrap
          .index
            h1 = student.register_no
          .name
            h3 = student.name
          .grade
            h1 U
            h5 x20.21
          .arrow
            #arrow-toggle =image_tag('arrow.svg', class: ['arrow-down', 'test'])

        .collapsible-body
          .wrap-content
            .station-grade A: <12.01s
            .station-grade B: 12.01 - 13.11
            .station-grade C: 13.11 - 14.11
            .station-grade D: 14.21 - 15.11
            .station-grade E: 15.31 - 16.51

          .score-input
            = f.input '#', label: false, wrapper: false, input_html: { class: ['result-entry-textbox'], value: @station_score }
            button#result-entry-save.result-save-button SAVE
```

JQuery

```
$('#result-entry-save').click(function() {
    var checkIsNum = /^\d+$/.test('#result-entry-textbox');
    if(isNaN(checkIsNum)) {
      alert('not num');
    } else {
      alert('is num');
  }
});
```

Comment: Try using a class instead of id for the button and textbox and change the selector to class in JS

Comment: yes I agree with @Pavan as you have more than 1 buttons so you need to mention class in your view because if you use id as a selector in JS it will search/ find with id with first entry only,

Comment: @pavan Thank you!

Comment: @DivyaSharma Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
$('#result-entry-save').click(function() {
    $('input[type="textbox"]').each(function(){ 
        var checkIsNum = /^\d+$/.test($(this));
        if(isNaN(checkIsNum)) {
          alert('not num');
        } else {
          alert('is num');
        }
    });
});
```

Or You can add common class to the input-boxes you want to check and then do like below:-

```
$('#result-entry-save').click(function() {
    $('.common-class-name').each(function(){ 
        var checkIsNum = /^\d+$/.test($(this));
        if(isNaN(checkIsNum)) {
          alert('not num');
        } else {
          alert('is num');
        }
  });
});
```

***Note:- instead of showing multiple alert you can do it in single alert like below:-***

```
$('#result-entry-save').click(function() {
    var checkval = true;
    $('input[type="textbox"]').each(function(){ 
        var checkIsNum = /^\d+$/.test($(this));
        if(isNaN(checkIsNum)) {
           checkval = false;
        } else {
          checkval = true;
        }
    });
    if(checkval == false){
        alert("some input fields have non-integer value.Check and correct!");return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: @Daniel  glad to help you :):)